# Problems loading HDR textures Vulkan

Tags: c++, vulkan

I am attempting to make a game engine. Currently I am trying to implement a HDR skybox which also has mip maps, however have been stuck with an error for a while. The Example runs completely fine loading non-HDR 8 bit colour textures. But the moment I attempt to use VK_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_SFLOAT (which I'm fairly sure is the correct format in order to correspond to 4 bit floats loaded from stbi) the command buffer fails to ever complete and seems to always be in a pending state, I have tried giving the texture manager its own command buffer with no luck and using both vkQueueWaitIdle as well as fences but they both return VK_SUCCEED. The validation layers then throw an error once vkResetCommandBuffer is invoked because the command buffer is in pending state. Seemingly it sometimes rarely works if I click to focus on the console, more errors appear afterwards but was not always the case and HDR seemed to be working once it loaded but was still a 1/3 occasion mostly throwing the same error.

This is the code that is used to load the cubemaps in:

```cpp
Cubemap::Cubemap(CubemapInfo cubemapInfo)
{
    RenderSystem& renderSystem = RenderSystem::instance();
    TextureManager& textureManager = TextureManager::instance();

    VkImageFormatProperties formatProperties;
    assert(("[ERROR] Unsupported texture format", !vkGetPhysicalDeviceImageFormatProperties(renderSystem.mPhysicalDevice, cubemapInfo.format, VK_IMAGE_TYPE_2D, VK_IMAGE_TILING_OPTIMAL, VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_SRC_BIT | VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT | VK_IMAGE_USAGE_SAMPLED_BIT, 0, &formatProperties)));

    FormatInfo formatInfo = getFormatInfo(cubemapInfo.format);

    #pragma region Create cubemap resources
    stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(true);

    void* textureData[6];
    // Load images
    int width, height, channels;
    bool hdr = cubemapInfo.format == VK_FORMAT_R16_SFLOAT || cubemapInfo.format == VK_FORMAT_R16G16_SFLOAT || cubemapInfo.format == VK_FORMAT_R16G16B16_SFLOAT || cubemapInfo.format == VK_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_SFLOAT || cubemapInfo.format == VK_FORMAT_R32_SFLOAT || cubemapInfo.format == VK_FORMAT_R32G32_SFLOAT || cubemapInfo.format == VK_FORMAT_R32G32B32_SFLOAT || cubemapInfo.format == VK_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_SFLOAT;
    if (hdr)
    {
        if (formatInfo.bytesPerChannel == 4)
        {
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                textureData[i] = stbi_loadf(cubemapInfo.directories[i].c_str(), &width, &height, &channels, formatInfo.nChannels);
            }
        }
        else if (formatInfo.bytesPerChannel == 2)
        {
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                float* data = stbi_loadf(cubemapInfo.directories[i].c_str(), &width, &height, &channels, formatInfo.nChannels);
                unsigned long long dataSize = width * height * formatInfo.nChannels;

                textureData[i] = new float16[dataSize];
                for (unsigned long long j = 0; j < dataSize; j++)
                {
                    ((float16*)textureData[i])[j] = floatToFloat16(data[j]);
                }
                stbi_image_free((void*)data);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            textureData[i] = stbi_load(cubemapInfo.directories[i].c_str(), &width, &height, &channels, formatInfo.nChannels);
        }
    }

    const VkDeviceSize imageSize = 6 * VkDeviceSize(width) * height * formatInfo.nChannels * formatInfo.bytesPerChannel;
    unsigned int nMips = unsigned int(std::floor(std::log2(width > height ? width : height))) + 1;

    assert(("[ERROR] Unsupported texture format", formatProperties.maxExtent.width >= width && formatProperties.maxExtent.height >= height && formatProperties.maxExtent.depth >= 1 && formatProperties.maxMipLevels >= 1 && formatProperties.maxArrayLayers >= 1 && formatProperties.sampleCounts & VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT && formatProperties.maxResourceSize >= imageSize));

    // Create image
    VkImageCreateInfo imageCreateInfo = {};
    imageCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_CREATE_INFO;
    imageCreateInfo.pNext = nullptr;
    imageCreateInfo.flags = VK_IMAGE_CREATE_CUBE_COMPATIBLE_BIT;
    imageCreateInfo.imageType = VK_IMAGE_TYPE_2D;
    imageCreateInfo.format = cubemapInfo.format;
    imageCreateInfo.extent = { unsigned int(width), unsigned int(height), 1 };
    imageCreateInfo.mipLevels = nMips;
    imageCreateInfo.arrayLayers = 6;
    imageCreateInfo.samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
    imageCreateInfo.tiling = VK_IMAGE_TILING_OPTIMAL;
    imageCreateInfo.usage = VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_SRC_BIT | VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT | VK_IMAGE_USAGE_SAMPLED_BIT;
    imageCreateInfo.sharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE;
    imageCreateInfo.queueFamilyIndexCount = 0;
    imageCreateInfo.pQueueFamilyIndices = nullptr;
    imageCreateInfo.initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
    VkResult result = vkCreateImage(renderSystem.mDevice, &imageCreateInfo, nullptr, &mImage);
    validateResult(result);

    VkMemoryRequirements memoryRequirements;
    vkGetImageMemoryRequirements(renderSystem.mDevice, mImage, &memoryRequirements);

    VkMemoryAllocateInfo memoryAllocateInfo = {};
    memoryAllocateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_MEMORY_ALLOCATE_INFO;
    memoryAllocateInfo.allocationSize = memoryRequirements.size;
    memoryAllocateInfo.memoryTypeIndex = memoryTypeFromProperties(renderSystem.mPhysicalDeviceMemoryProperties, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT);
    result = vkAllocateMemory(renderSystem.mDevice, &memoryAllocateInfo, nullptr, &mImageMemory);
    validateResult(result);

    result = vkBindImageMemory(renderSystem.mDevice, mImage, mImageMemory, 0);
    validateResult(result);

    // Create staging buffer
    VkBuffer stagingBuffer;
    VkDeviceMemory stagingMemory;

    VkBufferCreateInfo bufferCreateInfo = {};
    bufferCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_BUFFER_CREATE_INFO;
    bufferCreateInfo.pNext = nullptr;
    bufferCreateInfo.flags = 0;
    bufferCreateInfo.size = imageSize;
    bufferCreateInfo.usage = VK_BUFFER_USAGE_TRANSFER_SRC_BIT;
    bufferCreateInfo.sharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE;
    bufferCreateInfo.queueFamilyIndexCount = 0;
    bufferCreateInfo.pQueueFamilyIndices = nullptr;
    result = vkCreateBuffer(renderSystem.mDevice, &bufferCreateInfo, nullptr, &stagingBuffer);
    validateResult(result);

    vkGetBufferMemoryRequirements(renderSystem.mDevice, stagingBuffer, &memoryRequirements);

    memoryAllocateInfo.allocationSize = memoryRequirements.size;
    memoryAllocateInfo.memoryTypeIndex = memoryTypeFromProperties(renderSystem.mPhysicalDeviceMemoryProperties, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT);
    result = vkAllocateMemory(renderSystem.mDevice, &memoryAllocateInfo, nullptr, &stagingMemory);
    validateResult(result);

    result = vkBindBufferMemory(renderSystem.mDevice, stagingBuffer, stagingMemory, 0);
    validateResult(result);

    unsigned char* data;
    result = vkMapMemory(renderSystem.mDevice, stagingMemory, 0, imageSize, 0, (void**)&data);
    validateResult(result);

    unsigned long long dataLayer = unsigned long long(width) * height * formatInfo.nChannels * formatInfo.bytesPerChannel;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        memcpy((void*)(data + i * dataLayer), textureData[i], dataLayer);
        stbi_image_free(textureData[i]);
    }

    vkUnmapMemory(renderSystem.mDevice, stagingMemory);

    result = vkBeginCommandBuffer(textureManager.mCommandBuffer, &renderSystem.mCommandBufferBeginInfo);
    validateResult(result);

    VkImageMemoryBarrier barrier = {};
    barrier.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_MEMORY_BARRIER;
    barrier.pNext = nullptr;
    barrier.srcAccessMask = 0;
    barrier.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT /* Additional >> */ | VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_READ_BIT;
    barrier.oldLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
    barrier.newLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL;
    barrier.srcQueueFamilyIndex = VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED;
    barrier.dstQueueFamilyIndex = VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED;
    barrier.image = mImage;
    barrier.subresourceRange.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
    barrier.subresourceRange.baseMipLevel = 0;
    barrier.subresourceRange.levelCount = nMips;
    barrier.subresourceRange.baseArrayLayer = 0;
    barrier.subresourceRange.layerCount = 6;
    vkCmdPipelineBarrier(textureManager.mCommandBuffer, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT, 0, 0, nullptr, 0, nullptr, 1, &barrier);

    VkBufferImageCopy copyRegion = {};
    copyRegion.bufferOffset = 0;
    copyRegion.bufferRowLength = 0;
    copyRegion.bufferImageHeight = 0;
    copyRegion.imageSubresource.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
    copyRegion.imageSubresource.mipLevel = 0;
    copyRegion.imageSubresource.baseArrayLayer = 0;
    copyRegion.imageSubresource.layerCount = 6;
    copyRegion.imageOffset = { 0, 0, 0 };
    copyRegion.imageExtent = { unsigned int(width), unsigned int(height), 1 };
    vkCmdCopyBufferToImage(textureManager.mCommandBuffer, stagingBuffer, mImage, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL, 1, &copyRegion);

    barrier.srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT;
    barrier.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_READ_BIT;
    barrier.oldLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL;
    barrier.newLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL;
    barrier.subresourceRange.levelCount = 1;

    VkImageBlit imageBlit = {};
    imageBlit.srcSubresource.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
    imageBlit.srcSubresource.baseArrayLayer = 0;
    imageBlit.srcSubresource.layerCount = 6;
    imageBlit.dstSubresource.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
    imageBlit.dstSubresource.baseArrayLayer = 0;
    imageBlit.dstSubresource.layerCount = 6;

    unsigned int mipWidth = width, mipHeight = height;
    for (unsigned int i = 1; i < nMips; i++)
    {
        barrier.subresourceRange.baseMipLevel = i - 1;
        vkCmdPipelineBarrier(textureManager.mCommandBuffer, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT, 0, 0, nullptr, 0, nullptr, 1, &barrier);

        imageBlit.srcSubresource.mipLevel = i - 1;
        imageBlit.srcOffsets[0] = { 0, 0, 0 };
        imageBlit.srcOffsets[1] = { int(mipWidth), int(mipHeight), 1 };

        imageBlit.dstSubresource.mipLevel = i;
        if (mipWidth > 1)
            mipWidth /= 2;
        if (mipHeight > 1)
            mipHeight /= 2;
        imageBlit.dstOffsets[0] = { 0, 0, 0 };
        imageBlit.dstOffsets[1] = { int(mipWidth), int(mipHeight), 1 };

        vkCmdBlitImage(textureManager.mCommandBuffer, mImage, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL, mImage, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL, 1, &imageBlit, VK_FILTER_LINEAR);
    }

    barrier.srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT;
    barrier.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT;
    barrier.newLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < nMips; i++)
    {
        barrier.oldLayout = i == nMips - 1 ? VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL : VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_SRC_OPTIMAL;
        barrier.subresourceRange.baseMipLevel = i;
        vkCmdPipelineBarrier(textureManager.mCommandBuffer, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT, 0, 0, nullptr, 0, nullptr, 1, &barrier);
    }

    result = vkEndCommandBuffer(textureManager.mCommandBuffer);
    validateResult(result);

    VkSubmitInfo submitInfo = {};
    submitInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SUBMIT_INFO;
    submitInfo.pNext = nullptr;
    submitInfo.waitSemaphoreCount = 0;
    submitInfo.pWaitSemaphores = nullptr;
    submitInfo.pWaitDstStageMask = nullptr;
    submitInfo.commandBufferCount = 1;
    submitInfo.pCommandBuffers = &textureManager.mCommandBuffer;
    submitInfo.signalSemaphoreCount = 0;
    submitInfo.pSignalSemaphores = nullptr;
    result = vkQueueSubmit(renderSystem.mGraphicsQueue, 1, &submitInfo, NULL);
    validateResult(result);

    // Create image view
    VkImageViewCreateInfo imageViewCreateInfo = {};
    imageViewCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_VIEW_CREATE_INFO;
    imageViewCreateInfo.pNext = nullptr;
    imageViewCreateInfo.flags = 0;
    imageViewCreateInfo.image = mImage;
    imageViewCreateInfo.viewType = VK_IMAGE_VIEW_TYPE_CUBE;
    imageViewCreateInfo.format = cubemapInfo.format;
    imageViewCreateInfo.components = formatInfo.componentMapping;
    imageViewCreateInfo.subresourceRange.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
    imageViewCreateInfo.subresourceRange.baseMipLevel = 0;
    imageViewCreateInfo.subresourceRange.levelCount = nMips;
    imageViewCreateInfo.subresourceRange.baseArrayLayer = 0;
    imageViewCreateInfo.subresourceRange.layerCount = 6;
    result = vkCreateImageView(renderSystem.mDevice, &imageViewCreateInfo, nullptr, &mImageView);
    validateResult(result);

    // Create sampler
    VkSamplerCreateInfo samplerCreateInfo = {};
    samplerCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SAMPLER_CREATE_INFO;
    samplerCreateInfo.pNext = nullptr;
    samplerCreateInfo.flags = 0;
    samplerCreateInfo.magFilter = VK_FILTER_LINEAR;
    samplerCreateInfo.minFilter = VK_FILTER_LINEAR;
    samplerCreateInfo.mipmapMode = VK_SAMPLER_MIPMAP_MODE_LINEAR;
    samplerCreateInfo.mipLodBias = 0.0f;
    samplerCreateInfo.minLod = 0.0f;
    samplerCreateInfo.maxLod = float(nMips);
    samplerCreateInfo.addressModeU = VK_SAMPLER_ADDRESS_MODE_REPEAT;;
    samplerCreateInfo.addressModeV = VK_SAMPLER_ADDRESS_MODE_REPEAT;
    samplerCreateInfo.addressModeW = VK_SAMPLER_ADDRESS_MODE_REPEAT;
    samplerCreateInfo.anisotropyEnable = VK_TRUE;
    samplerCreateInfo.maxAnisotropy = renderSystem.mPhysicalDeviceProperties.limits.maxSamplerAnisotropy;
    samplerCreateInfo.compareEnable = VK_FALSE;
    samplerCreateInfo.compareOp = VK_COMPARE_OP_ALWAYS;
    samplerCreateInfo.borderColor = VK_BORDER_COLOR_INT_OPAQUE_BLACK;
    samplerCreateInfo.unnormalizedCoordinates = VK_FALSE;
    result = vkCreateSampler(renderSystem.mDevice, &samplerCreateInfo, nullptr, &mSampler);
    validateResult(result);

    result = vkQueueWaitIdle(renderSystem.mGraphicsQueue);
    validateResult(result);
    result = vkResetCommandBuffer(textureManager.mCommandBuffer, 0);
    validateResult(result);

    vkDestroyBuffer(renderSystem.mDevice, stagingBuffer, nullptr);
    vkFreeMemory(renderSystem.mDevice, stagingMemory, nullptr);
    #pragma endregion
}
```

Exact errors that occurr:

VUID-vkResetCommandBuffer-commandBuffer-00045(ERROR / SPEC): msgNum: 511214570 - Validation Error: [ VUID-vkResetCommandBuffer-commandBuffer-00045 ] Object 0: handle = 0x19323492138, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER; | MessageID = 0x1e7883ea | Attempt to reset VkCommandBuffer 0x19323492138[] which is in use. The Vulkan spec states: commandBuffer must not be in the pending state (https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.2.162.1/windows/1.2-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-vkResetCommandBuffer-commandBuffer-00045)
Objects: 1
[0] 0x19323492138, type: 6, name: NULL

UNASSIGNED-CoreValidation-DrawState-InvalidImageLayout(ERROR / SPEC): msgNum: 1303270965 - Validation Error: [ UNASSIGNED-CoreValidation-DrawState-InvalidImageLayout ] Object 0: handle = 0x19323492138, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER; | MessageID = 0x4dae5635 | Submitted command buffer expects VkImage 0x5fb0e800000000cd[] (subresource: aspectMask 0x1 array layer 0, mip level 0) to be in layout VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL--instead, current layout is VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED.
Objects: 1
[0] 0x19323492138, type: 6, name: NULL

(^ This error is thrown continuously for mip levels 0-12 ^)

View full source:
https://github.com/finnbuhse/Vulkan-Engine-V1.0

Although assets and shader binaries are not on the github so compile the shader sources into files with names identical to those found in mesh.cpp line 1083 and adjust main.cpp to include custom models if you wish to try compile and run the source.

Any clue as to why this might be happening would be greatly appreciated

Comment: It's not really related to your problem, but I reckon you'll end up switching to `VK_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_SFLOAT` in the end because it has mandatory support for `VK_FORMAT_FEATURE_SAMPLED_IMAGE_FILTER_LINEAR_BIT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after almost an entire year of agonising over this one error... I found what seemed to have happened was the GPU memory ran out, and the skybox I picked initially was simply too large; each face was 4K and I found the whole cubemap had to be allocated over a gigabyte of video memory, and having a mere NVIDIA GTX 1050 Ti, is a quarter of it. However I did think this was possible early on, which is why I validated every VkResult I could thinking if this happened, VK_ERROR_OUT_OF_DEVICE_MEMORY would be returned. However nothing but success from what the 'results' could tell. Perhaps it wasn't so much video memory but the GPU had a hard time mip-mapping such a large image. Either way, with a different HDR skybox (1k) it works perfectly fine with both 16 bit floating point images aswell as 32 bits.

Comment: You may mark this as an answer. Make sure to edit the answer to make it clear on what you did, in case others might search it up.

Comment: @Alex All I did was change to a lower res skybox. I have changed the code in the question to be capable of loading 16 bit floats also, like Columbo mentioned for other poeple to examine if they want to load a HDR mip-mapped cubemap. If you have stbi you could alternatively use the whole files Texture.h and Texture.cpp on my github

Comment: Great. Think of it this way, when someone reading about 'Vulkan' queries a similar question, your answer should be clear enough to provide the needed information for the user. Hence marking it as the best answer.